# how to track changes to PageCollectionView SortDescriptions

Tags: silverlight, pagedcollectionview

When a `DataGrid` is bound to a `PagedCollectionView` the user can resort the data of a given column or collection of columns.  This user action manipulates the `SortDescriptions` collection and when that happens I need to refresh the underlying data with a new query from the server.

Ideally I would attach an event handler to `CollectionChanged` event of the `SortDescriptions` property, but I can't since it's is protected.

What then is the correct method for tracking changes to the `SortDescriptions` collection of the `PagedCollectionView`?

Comment: Are you using WCF RIA Services (DomainService on serverside and DomainContext on clientside)?

Comment: Yes I am using RIA Services on the serverside and DomainContext on the client side.  Although I'm not sure why that should matter?  Perhaps there's a piece of plumbing that I'm fully understanding?

Comment: No, i thought that the DomainCollectionView could help you to do want you want. But using this class you have the same problem. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a simple matter of casting the SortDescriptions property to an INotifyCollectionChanged which will expose the CollectionChanged event.

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)Data.SortDescriptions).CollectionChanged += (s,e)=> { ... };
```